# Insert data on multi tables on PHP with MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm trying to create a program that register all the electronic equipment and partner it to an employee (eg: we buy a computer and give it to employee "Mark") and on that WebApp I want to register the item and parter it to the user/employee.
I've already tried something but Im not getting to where I want, on MySQL I have 3 tables:

- Ativos
- Users
- Event

Where items are the equipment, users are the employee and event are the regist of the equipment 
But on the PHP code, I don't know how to do it, how can I set a page with PHP where I can input data from the 3 tables?
I have the following code:

```
if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,anexo,anexo_a,numero_serie,imei,ativo_sap,evento,data_entrega,data_devolucao,data_estravio,username) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,$anexo,$anexo_a,$numero_serie,$imei,$ativo_sap,$evento,$data_entrega,$data_devolucao,$data_estravio,$username));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its Very simple my friend , if you would like to insert values into 3 tables with single  query statement then only try this.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("your_hostname","your_user","your_password","your_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
$sql="INSERT INTO Table_1 
      (
        FieldName1,
        FieldName2,
        FieldName3
      ) 
      VALUES 
      (
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3
      );
      INSERT INTO Table_2 
      (
        FieldName1,
        FieldName2,
        FieldName3
      ) 
      VALUES 
      (
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3
      );
      INSERT INTO Table_3 
      (
        FieldName1,
        FieldName2,
        FieldName3
      ) 
      VALUES 
      (
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3
      );";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, and then the php code to input still the same? I mean, the vars where I have stored the inputs

Comment: I didn't knew it was that simple...
Thank you so much :D

Comment: My pleasure :) .